# How to fetch description from config file

Tags: python

How to fetch the description  from the config file?
From the API response the  output like this

```
[{'id':  'pc_fan_problem'}]
```

from this we want to fetch 'id' and then we want to fetch the description from config file for every id

sample confile file like this

```
pc_fan_problem="i having   problem with pc_fan_problem"
pc_reset="i having problem with 
pc_reset"
pc_battery_low="i having   problem with pc_battery_low"
```

Final output like this

```
[{'pc_fan_problem':'i having  problem with pc_fan_problem'}]
```

Comment: `[('id':  'pc_fan_problem'}]` is invalid syntax, please correct your API response output.

Comment: The Api response is [{ 'id' : 'pc_fan_problem' }]

Comment: @Tech what @BioGeek meant is, the syntax is invalid in your question. It should be a curly brace instead of round brace. Incorrect: `[('id': 'pc_fan_problem'}]`, Correct: `[{ 'id' : 'pc_fan_problem' }]`. Notice the curly brace at the beginning. Please edit the question with correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the API response, we can get the result with something like this

```py
response = [{'id': 'pc_fan_problem'}]
problem = response[0]['id']  # since response is a list of dicts
result = []  # initialise an empty list
with open('file.config', 'r') as config:
    for line in config.readlines():
        if line.startswith(problem):
            # Assuming each line has different problem and its description, select 2nd element of the resulting list
            description = line.split('=')[1]  # line.split('=') -> ['pc_fan_problem', '"i having   problem with pc_fan_problem"\n']
            description = description.strip("\n")  # '"i having   problem with pc_fan_problem"\n' -> '"i having   problem with pc_fan_problem"'
            result.append({problem:description})
print(result)  # result -> [{'pc_fan_problem': '"i having   problem with pc_fan_problem"'}]
```

This is a very basic approach, please feel free to modify it according to your needs.